# Telegram Bot. Cant find reason of exception

Tags: java, telegram-bot

I used this example to create Telegram Bot. I did all code the same.
Checking of my bot in web - gives this:

```
{"ok":true,"result":{"id":523022396,"is_bot":true,"first_name":"KamazBot","username":"Kamazi_bot"}}
```

changes only in this:

```
@Override 
public String getBotUsername() { 
return "XXX";//my bot name 
} 
@Override 
public String getBotToken() { 
return "XXX"; //my bot token 
}
```

========================================================================
it seems to me that  implementation the methods getBotUsername and getBotToken are configured correctly.

when i start my app - it shows:

```
org.telegram.telegrambots.exceptions.TelegramApiRequestException: Error removing old webhook: [401] Unauthorized
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot.clearWebhook(TelegramLongPollingBot.java:49)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.TelegramBotsApi.registerBot(TelegramBotsApi.java:120)
    at Main.main(Main.java:17)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

what is the problem in ?

Comment: What is you bot token format?

Comment: Error says: [401] Unauthorized. This means that you may have typo in username or toke. Check in documentation what format of token is expected and if it shouldn't be encoded somehow.

Comment: OK. thanks. it works now. the Token-String was not correct/

Answer (score 0):

Check the token. For some reason, authorization does not occur. Check your credentials